# Django, edit device info making duplicate entry while keeping the old entry as well

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have created a below function to update the device info in my django app, it does update the device information but also keeping the old data in the table, it should overwrite rather than duplicating the previous entry with the updated change.

can someone please take a look and suggest ?

```
def updateDevice(request, id):
    hostlist_upt = HostList.objects.get(id__exact=id)
    form = HostListForm(instance=hostlist_upt)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HostListForm(request.POST, instance=hostlist_upt)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/devices')
    
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "add_device.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The new data has to be saved to the instance it belongs to.
In this case you need to change

```
def updateDevice(request, id):
    hostlist_upt = HostList.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HostListForm(request.POST, instance=hostlist_upt)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/devices')
    else:
        form = HostListForm(instance=hostlist_upt)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "add_device.html", context)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but that did not make any change, same results

Comment: `def updateDevice(request, id):
    hostlist_upt = HostList.objects.get(id__exact=id)
    form = HostListForm(instance=hostlist_upt)
    # form = HostListForm(request.POST, instance=hostlist_upt)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HostListForm(request.POST, instance=hostlist_upt)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(instance=hostlist_upt)
        return redirect('/devices')
    
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "add_device.html", context)'

Comment: :( again no difference, I want to show you my add_device.html, just in case if my href looks OK ? 

```      <form method="POST" action="/add_device/">
        {% csrf_token %}```

Comment: Please show your html and forms.py file. Maybe then I can help with success :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in my add_device.html page, I removed the following href and duplication stopped, I tried my original code what I pasted in the beginning and it looks fine now. It may be because it was routing to that add_device view instead of updateDevice view.

> ```
>   <form method="POST" action="/add_device">
>     {% csrf_token
> ```

change it to

> ```
>   <form method="POST" action="">
>     {% csrf_token
> ```

Thank you ViLuWi